# How to pass a parameter from Shell to WLST script

Tags: bash, weblogic, wlst

EDIT: The issue is solved. But I keep it here so others will benefit from here. If it is not okay, I will delete the question.

I want to stop servers in an order automatically . So I have written scripts one with python the other with bash for that matter. The WLST script

```
import sys
managedserver = sys.argv[1]
#while True:
#   try:
#   connect('weblogic', 'weblogic1', 't3://machine-1:7001')
#   break
#   
#   except Exception:
#   print("can't connect to AdminServer")
connect('weblogic', 'welcome1', 't3://machine-1:7001')

shutdown(managedserver,ignoreSessions='false', force='false')
#if state(managedserver,name='managedserver') == 'SUSPENDED':
#   time.sleep(60)
#   shutdown(managedserver,name='managedserver',ignoreSessions='true', force='true')
#elif state(managedserver,name='managedserver') == 'RUNNING':
#   shutdown('managedserver',name='managedserver',ignoreSessions='true', force='true')
#else:
#   break

exit()
```

I invoke that script with the following script.

```
echo "############################"
echo "# All Servers are STOPPING #"
echo "############################"
# Shutting down servers
WLST_Bin=/data/mw/12213/wls/ohome/oracle_common/common/bin
for managedserver in MOBIL-TEST-S01-2201 MOBIL-TEST-S01-2202
do 
    echo " Shutting Down ${server} !!! "
    sh ${WLST_Bin}/wlst.sh ServerStop.py $managedserver
    sleep 600
    
done
```

The error I get is `WLSTException: Error occurred while performing shutdown : No server, cluster, system component or system component configuration with name "managedserver" configured in the domain`

It is due to I can't pass parameter to WLST script. I searched online but could't find anything.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Yeap I know that, as I said it is at the line where it tries to connect. Thanks for the info it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to WLST script. You should be reading it using `sys.argv[i].`

Sample:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    decrypt(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```